# OnClick or something inside Select

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

My select option looks this way,

```
<select class="chosen">
    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Add new criteria</option>                                          
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <option value="" onclick="ShowMessage(@item.Criteria);">@item.Criteria</option>
    }
</select>
```

The foreach loop has somewhere around 20 values i need individual values of them when they are clicked..I cannot use onclick on select because values are inside foreach.
My jquery

```
function ShowMessage(criteria) {
    alert(criteria);
}
```

Let me know what to use instead of `onclick=""` because isn't working...

Comment: I think you are looking for the change event

Comment: Yes, should work inside foreach which is inside select...

Comment: `onclick="ShowMessage('@item.Criteria');"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), You should bind `change` event using it.

*HTML*

```
<select class="chosen">
    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Add new criteria</option>                                          
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <option value="" data-criteria="@item.Criteria">@item.Criteria</option>
    }
</select>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen').on('change', function(){
        var criteria = $(this).find('option:selected').data('criteria');
        //As per your current html, you can use .text() also 
        //var criteria = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        alert(criteria);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `change` event from `jQuery`. Your `@foreach` will change like below.

**Note:** I think you forgot to add `value="@item.Criteria"` to the `option` tag.

```
<select class="chosen">
    <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Add new criteria</option>                                          
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <option value="@item.Criteria">@item.Criteria</option>
    }
</select>
```

And you add `.change` event on `select` that will alert the value.

```
$('.chosen').change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

```js
$('.chosen').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="chosen">
  <option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>Add new criteria</option>
  <option value="Criteria1">Criteria1</option>
  <option value="Criteria2">Criteria2</option>
  <option value="Criteria3">Criteria3</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on option elements will fail in some browsers. You should rather bind the change event on select element, and then get selected option in it:

```
$('select.chosen').change(function(){
   alert($(this).find('option:selected').text())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as follow:-

```
<option value="" onclick="ShowMessage('@item.Criteria');">@item.Criteria</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call Change function of select box

```
$(".chosen").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

and you can also get select value without calling change method like

```
alert($(".chosen").val());
```